# Changing client devices settings for all users in AD group

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, batch-file

I have over 40 users in an Active Directory that need client printers disabled so I can go back and allow only a select few users this without disabling through TSconfig. Really looking for a script or something that can change enviornment settings for all the users so I can manually allow 3 of 40 AD users to use client printers. Is this possible without a Citrix policy?

Comment: I think your asking about the AD profile setting for terminal server features?  If so try joeqwerty's ADModify.NET which is awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a script but you can use [ADModify.NET](http://admodify.codeplex.com/) to achieve this.